# Elasticsearch and low cardinality searches

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with about 30 million records, or 20 fields.

I'm contemplating adding a Yes/No binary flag to each record that indicates if it is in one group or another. The split will be roughly 50/50.

Every search will require to look at the Yes/No field, in addition to others.

Am I best to do this, or have two indexes, and search across both?

Comment: You can use `type`. Create two types in the same index and put documents of one group in first type and other group in second type.

Comment: posted as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type`.

Create two types within a same index. Put documents of one group in type1 and other group in type2.
Then you can perform search like

```
GET /index/type1/_search
```

This will fetch you all the documents of type1.

Comment: isn't it a wrong and confusing usage of type? :) I mean semantically it should be the same type of documents. (well, not quite clear from the question)